# remove the record from mysql based on time

Tags: java, javascript, mysql

I am working with google maps. When i select any location on the map, it gives lat, long values.

Additionally I am adding two more columns time( 2014-02-21 12:36:08),and expected time(10 minutes).

I am inserted all these values into mysql database.

I am trying  to delete the records which matches condition ( (record insert time + expected time) > current time ), which means the sum is greater than current system time the record has to delete automatically, it is not endless if expected time may be change in feature.

Please give me any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE DATE_ADD(INSERT_TIME, INTERVAL EXPECTED_TIME MINUTE) > NOW()
```

Comment: DATE_ADD function will add EXPECTED_TIME(10 minute) in INSERT_TIME and it will be checked with NOW() (current time), which will be deleted, may you get this. also you can check using SELECT query using same WHERE condition

Comment: before i send this query to database,i need do something for when this query has to go